# Url amigável entre containers/imagens docker

Tags: docker

Estou com alguns projetos já prontos que utilizarão Docker, porém eles ficarão em imagens separadas.

A dúvida é a seguinte: É possível outras imagens serem acessadas através de uma "url amigável".

Exemplo:

- Container principal está em `www.teste.com`
- E os outro serem acessados assim: `www.teste.com/projeto2`, `www.teste.com/projeto3`, sendo que seriam outros containers.

Answer (score 1):

Dá pra resolver seu problema por meio de diversas abordagens. A que eu usaria seria da seguinte forma.

Um único container seria responsável por responder às requisições por meio da URL `www.teste.com`, como se fosse um load balancer. Esse container receberia as requisições dos caminhos e, dependendo do caminho, faria outra requisição para um segundo container. Essa estratégia é você quem decide.

Para o meu load balancer, escrevi um código em Go que recebe a requisição e a repassa para outro servidor com base no caminho chamado:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "io/ioutil"
    "log"
    "net/http"
)

func router(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {

    var url string

    switch r.URL.Path {
    case "/stack":
        url = "http://app1.dev" + r.URL.Path
    case "/overflow":
        url = "http://app2.dev" + r.URL.Path
    default:
        url = "http://app3.dev" + r.URL.Path
    }

    resp, err := http.Get(url)
    if err != nil {
        w.WriteHeader(500)
        w.Write([]byte(fmt.Sprintf("Could not call '%s'.\n", url)))
    }

    body, err := ioutil.ReadAll(resp.Body)
    if err != nil {
        w.WriteHeader(500)
        w.Write([]byte(fmt.Sprintf("Could not read '%s'.\n", url)))
    }

    w.WriteHeader(resp.StatusCode)
    w.Write(body)
}

func main() {
    http.HandleFunc("/", router)
    err := http.ListenAndServe(":80", nil)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal("ListenAndServe: ", err)
    }
}
```

Para orquestrar os containers, optei por escrever um `docker-compose.yml`, no qual eu discrimino todos os containers da aplicação:

```
mm_lb:
  image: mm/lb:latest
  container_name: mm_lb
  links:
    - mm_app1:app1.dev
    - mm_app2:app2.dev
    - mm_app3:app3.dev
  ports:
    - "80"

mm_app1:
  image: mm/app1:latest
  container_name: mm_app1
  ports:
    - "80"

mm_app2:
  image: mm/app2:latest
  container_name: mm_app2
  ports:
    - "80"

mm_app3:
  image: mm/app3:latest
  container_name: mm_app3
  ports:
    - "80"
```

Repare que a configuração referente ao container `mm_lb` cria links com outros containers. É assim que consigo chamá-los a partir do load balancer que, por sua vez, responde à URL principal.

Answer (score 1):

Docker faz apenas redirecionamento de portas. A distribuição com base na url, é uma capacidade atendida por webservers e load balancers.

[Nginx](https://hub.docker.com/_/nginx/), ou [HAProxy](https://hub.docker.com/_/haproxy/) são excelentes opções para fazer esse tipo de distribuição. 
Ambos são muito conhecidos, utilizá-los é um pattern ainda sem nome, mas é possível vê-los presentes em diversos diagramas que apresentam múltiplos containers.

Ambos possuem extensa documentação disponível para pesquisa, mas o Nginx é mais simples.

Se estiver usando swarm, então qualquer worker do seu parque poderá redirecionar o trafego para o container adequado, isso é feito de forma transparente, no entanto é ideal colocar um loadbalancer para gerenciar isso.